# Insert Dict into wx Python List Ctrl

Tags: wxpython

I have a List Ctrl object with several columns.  I would like to insert a dict that I have generated through pandas into the list ctrl.  Can someone please help me with this?

Sample Code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('some_file.csv',header=None)
someDict = df.to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the ObjectListView widget instead. It's a wrapper for wx.ListCtrl, but with additional functionality. Basically, you could iterate over the CSV file and create a list of objects based on the columns in the file. Then you just load that list into the ObjectListView widget.

See the following links for more information:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/ObjectListView

Comment: Objectlistview can work directly with dictionaries as well as lists.

Comment: Yeah...I had forgotten about that